# Tile placement (wall and floor)

Tags: bathroom, walls, tile, floor

Is it wrong if the bathroom floor tiles' ends are not under the wall tiles? Does that affect a bathroom's ability to repel water?

P.S.: My contractor tiled the walls first and even though he left some gap between the floor and the first tiles on the wall, it is not sufficient for all the floor tiles to be placed under it..

Comment: Your bathroom? Is this a shower? (I've never understood the slop-sink expectation some folks apply to their bathroom walls.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always going to be a grout line as long as the void is filled and it dosent look bad compared to the width of the other grout lines it will be fine once sealed.

Answer (score 1):

The order doesn't matter; if moisture is your concern then that has to be addressed before tile ever gets installed. It is 100% guaranteed that water will find its way under the tile if this is a wet area. Water-proofing is something that's done during the prep stage.